# Is there a way to override ConsulProperties ignoring bootstrap.yml?

Tags: java, spring-boot, overriding, consul

I'm working on spring-boot application with consul integration. It communicates with consul by native spring-boot consul support (@EnableDiscoveryClient annotation and bootstrap.yml config file).

Sometimes, at application start, i need to change the host and port for connection to consul but i can't achieve this goal.

I tried to override ConsulProperties bean and change properties at ApplicationRunner implementation but consul still gets all initial values from config file...

How can i override consul properties or where can i insert my code to change initial settings or bootstrap.yml config values?

Comment: have you tried removing bootstrap.yml from classpath/resource path??

Comment: yes, without bootstrap.yml it doesn't work...

Comment: pardon me for asking this question why do you want to change host and port of consul every time?? and, You can change properties in bootstrap.yml itself which connects to provided host and port.

Comment: I have two reasons, for doing this:
a) i need to use my application in a docker container, where consul host and port are environment variables that shoudl be passed to application, so i can't write a certain consul host and port into bootstrap.yml
b) the second slant is that the project is legacy and i can't use spring boot and consul annotations :(